# How can I unbind a key in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

`M-return` is interfering with export (`M-return e e`) and other functions that I use a lot.

I tried `(define-key org-mode-map kbd "M-return" nil)`,
but after loading that (with `M-m f e r`, since I am using Spacemacs), I still get the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried this:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map kbd "M-return" nil)
```

Try this instead:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-return>") nil)
```

You made two mistakes: `kbd` is a function, and you want to pass it as argument the key description that Emacs shows you when you use `C-h k` and hit <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.  That mean use the sexp `(kbd ...)`, where `...` is what `C-h k` shows: `<M-return>`.

Comment: That solves it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote then. ;-)